# Navigate to the same view but with a different parameters

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to create a launchpad app using a list of tiles, the problem is that when I click in a tile it could be a app then I navigate to app url or it could be an group of apps or other groups than I need to navigate to the same view of the launchpad but with a new list of tiles. For now, I just want to navigate to navigate to the same view when I click in a tile and do it with slide transition but if I create a route with the same target of default route the view does not render when I start the application, it only works if I ser the target of the route when I create an other target with the same view name.

where is a part of my manifest:

```json
 "routes": [
        {
          "pattern": "",
          "name": "group",
          "target": "group"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "group",
          "name": "group2",
          "target": "group2"
        }
      ],
      "targets": {
        "group": {
          "viewName": "TileGroup",
          "viewLevel" : 1
        },
        "group2": {
          "viewName": "TileGroup",
          "viewLevel" : 2
        }
      }
    }
```

ans here the controller of my TileGroup view for now.

```js
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
],
sap.ui.controller("pelissari.soficom.launchpad.controller.TileGroup", {
 onInit: function() {
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   oModel.loadData("./model/data.json");
   this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  
 },
  onPress: function (oEvent) {
   var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
   oRouter.navTo("group2");
  }
 }));
```

With this code I think that the navigation is working because the url of the app changes when I click in a tile but the view do not change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are seeing the URL being changed, then you have the first part of the solution ready. The only thing is that you shouldn't navigate to a new target. Instead, you should navigate to the same target, but passing another tilegroup identifier using the second parameter of the `navTo` method, e.g.:

```
oRouter.navTo("tileView", {group: "group1"});
```

The second part involves getting an event raised in your controller whenever the URL changes, so that you can act on the change.

To catch the ID passed using the `navTo` method, you should change the route pattern in your manifest accordingly, e.g.:

```
"pattern": "tiles/:group:"
```

`tiles` indicates a fixed part in your URL, while `:group:` specifies an optional parameter called `group`. If you want to do this from the root (I think that's what you planned to do), it should be

```
"pattern": ":group:"
```

To inform the router that you want to get triggered when the URL changes, you can set a call-back. You can do so by inserting the code below into the onInit handler of your controller:

```
var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
oRouter.getRoute("group").attachPatternMatched(this._onPatternMatched, this);
```

When this is in your onInit handler, the `_onPatternMatched` handler is invoked when there was a change in the URL that involves target `group`. The latter is useful, otherwise your method would get triggered for every URL change, even when the view linked to your controller is not visible.

From the `_onPatternMatched` method, you should read back what the group ID is that should be displayed, so that you can change the tiles. You can do this by reading the `arguments` parameter from the event parameter:

```
_onObjectMatched : function (oEvent) {
    var groupId =  oEvent.getParameter("arguments").group;
    console.log("Group ID: " + groupId);
},
```

The essentials of routing are very well explained in the [UI5 walk-through](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html) step [31](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html), [32](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef.html) and [33](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8ef57cfd37b44f089f7e3b52d56597eb.html). Please especially take note of part 32, which explains routing with parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I will not say that works because we decide to just filter the list of tiles when the user press the tile, but thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Guto Pretty sure you'll get across an app where you need to do this again. So gaining this knowledge is definitely not a loss.

Comment: @jpenninkhof Any idea how I could force the View to be separately instantiated for each route/target?